# Is there anyway to reduce the height of the caption header in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, height, jqgrid-asp.net

Is there anyway to reduce height of the 'vendor details' part in jqGrid?

[image]

```
<script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="scripts/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
<script src="scripts/trirand/i18n/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="scripts/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.ColumnChooser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.ContextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%--<script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

<link href="css/themes/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/themes/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
<link href="css/themes/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<style type="text/css">     
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    height: 20px;   
    color:#cc961a;
} 
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-caption { height: 5px }
#button{   
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;     
text-align:center;
padding:2px 5px;
background:#ccc;
```

jQuery("#jqgItemDetails").jqGrid({
            url: '',
            datatype: "local",
            colNames: ['UPC Code', 'OLD UPC', 'Item Description', 'Old Item Desc', 'Size UOM', 'Old Size UOM', 'Department', 'Category',
                'Tax Description', 'WIC/CVV', 'Label', 'Last Movement', 'Last Purchase', 'Item Added', 'Comment', 'Store Number'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'UPC_Code', index: 'UPC_Code', width: 90, stype: 'text' },
                        { name: 'UPC_Code_Old', index: 'UPC_Code_Old', width: 90, stype: 'text', hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Item_Desc', index: 'Item_Desc', width: 150 },
                         { name: 'Item_Desc_Old', index: 'Item_Desc_Old', width: 150, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Size_UOM', index: 'Size_UOM', width: 60 },
                        { name: 'Size_UOM_Old', index: 'Size_UOM_Old', width: 60, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 80 },
                        { name: 'Tax_Desc', index: 'Tax_Desc', width: 150 },
                        { name: 'WIC_CVV', index: 'WIC_CVV', width: 80 },
                        { name: 'Label', index: 'Label', width: 150 },
                        { name: 'Last_Movement', index: 'Last_Movement', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Last_Purchase', index: 'Last_Purchase', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Item_Added', index: 'Item_Added', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Comment', index: 'Comment', width: 100, editable: true },
                        { name: 'Store_Number', index: 'Store_Number', width: 100, hidden: true }
                        ],
            multiselect: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'UPC_Code',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            pager: '#pager2',
            width: 1100,
            cellEdit: true,
            cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            editurl: '',
            height: 60,
            onSelectRow: editRow,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
                var grid = $("#jqgItemDetails");
                if (name == 'Comment') {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'Comment', val);
                }
            },
            caption: 'UPC Item Details'
        });

Comment: Please write always, which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). In general you should not have the problem. It could be that you have conflict with some other CSS rule used on the page. You can try to add CSS rule like `.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-caption { height: "auto" }` or to use some other value for the `height` instead of `"auto"`.

Comment: @Oleg : Thank you for the response. I tried your solution but not working. I am using jqGrid  5.2.0 free trial

Comment: I develop alternative fork: "free jqGrid". Probably tomorrow Tony will help you. Exists the same problem on demo pages of Guriddo? In any way, it's good to post **the demo**, which reproduce the problem or at least to post more details, which shows *how* you use jqGrid (which CSS: Bootstrap or jQuery UI, include JavaScript code and so on).

Comment: Please post  a demo and tell us which css framework is used? Also it seems to me that this is not the caption, but rather group header. Anyway without demo I can't help. Another important note - there is is no free trial jqGrid  It is just a trial. Current version of Guriddo jqGrid is 5.3 and 5.2 is old to be used as trial now

Comment: @tony tomov Edited the post with the jquery code and the script and the styles used.

Comment: @tony tomov : there is some other problems too.